# Constructing an Enum Value of Class type

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums

I have the following code:

```py
class Car:
  def __init__(self, id_):
    self.id = id_

class Train:
  def __init__(self, id_):
    self.id = id_

class TransportKind(Enum):
  One = Car
  Two = Train

class Transport:
  def __init__(self, transport_kind: TransportKind, other_value: int):
    self.transport_kind = transport_kind
    self.other_value = other_value
```

Now I want to construct a `Transport`:

```py
ts = Transport(transport_kind=TransportKind.One(id=5), other_value=2)
```

However this is not valid, since an Enum value cannot be constructed (`TypeError: 'TransportKind' object is not callable`)

How can I construct a TransportKind value?

Comment: `car : Car` does nothing, it doesn't create a class attribute. Creating class attributes is done with `car = ...` - but I'm not really sure of what you are really  trying to achieve here...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Typo mb, I updated my post.

Comment: you might be after an abstract factory pattern that returns a car/train factory based on the enum which in turn will create a car or train or such - but its qutie unclear to me what you aim at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum types (in other languages as well as Python) generally aren't meant to be made such that the type itself has data. I'm also confused, because traditionally, you don't want the enum type's name to be obscured. An enum is for classification amongst a discrete set of types/attributes. Traditionally, you would have a solution like the following:

```
from enum import Enum

class TransportKind(Enum):
    Car = 1
    Train = 2

class Transport(object):
    def __init__(self, transport_kind: TransportKind, other_value: int, **extra_data):
        self.transport_kind = transport_kind
        self.other_value = other_value
        for k, v in extra_data.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

...

ts = Transport(transport_kind=TransportKind.Car, other_value=2, id=5)
```

And somewhere, whereever relevant, you'd dispatch depending on `ts.transport_kind` to have different behavior and different expected attributes.

That said, an even more traditional-such approach is simply object-oriented programming:

```
class Transport(object):
    def __init__(self, id: int, other_value: int):
        self.id = id
        self.other_value = other_value

class Car(Transport):
    pass

class Train(Transport):
    pass

...

ts = Car(other_value=2, id=5)
```

Then later on use dispatching (dynamic, double using the visitor pattern, or even just a simple `instanceof` check) based on the class itself.

If you are so dead-set on doing things the way you propose, it would involve [subclassing Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing) or even subclassing the internal `EnumMeta` and altering its behavior, which gets very messy very quickly.

E: Fixed an assumption I made in the second example

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the `value` of your enumeration member (see [this part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes)):

```
ts = Transport(transport_kind=TransportKind.One.value(id_=5), other_value=2)
print(ts)
# <__main__.Transport object at 0x7f247f0e88b0>
```

But this looks like a strange use of enums anyway...

Comment: Accessing the value in this manner loses the behavior of the enum (classification to discrete type) because the `transport_kind` member is no longer of that enum, but an instance of that enum's value.